# How to configure FLUME-NG to write log to different log files according to the log sender IP?

Tags: hadoop, flume-ng

I am a newbie of FLUME. Just begin to use it (flume-ng). At present I have multiple application servers running on different servers. I want to collect the log of these servers. I install FLUME on a standalone LINUX computer. But I don't know how to config the FLUME to write the log to local files according to the application server IP Address. Or how to write the log according to different categories defined by me?

Answer (score 0):

Flume has an option for multiplexing the flow. This is an example from Flume-Ng user guide (https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html)

```
# list the sources, sinks and channels in the agent
agent_foo.sources = avro-AppSrv-source1
agent_foo.sinks = hdfs-Cluster1-sink1 avro-forward-sink2
agent_foo.channels = mem-channel-1 file-channel-2

# set channels for source
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.channels = mem-channel-1 file-channel-2

# set channel for sinks
agent_foo.sinks.hdfs-Cluster1-sink1.channel = mem-channel-1
agent_foo.sinks.avro-forward-sink2.channel = file-channel-2

# channel selector configuration
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.selector.type = multiplexing
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.selector.header = State
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.selector.mapping.CA = mem-channel-1
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.selector.mapping.AZ = file-channel-2
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.selector.mapping.NY = mem-channel-1 file-channel-2
agent_foo.sources.avro-AppSrv-source1.selector.default = mem-channel-1
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use flume channel selectors for simply routing event to different destinations. Or you can chain several flume agents together to implement complex routing function.
But the chained flume agents will become a little hard to maintain (resource usage and flume topology).
You can have a look at [flume-ng router sink](https://github.com/kylelin/flume-ng-router-sinks), it may provide some function you want.

First, add specific fields in event header by [flume interceptor](https://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-interceptors)

```
a1.sources = r1 r2
a1.channels = c1 c2
a1.sources.r1.channels =  c1
a1.sources.r1.type = seq
a1.sources.r1.interceptors = i1
a1.sources.r1.interceptors.i1.type = static
a1.sources.r1.interceptors.i1.key = ip
a1.sources.r1.interceptors.i1.value = 192.168.0.12
a1.sources.r2.channels =  c2
a1.sources.r2.type = seq
a1.sources.r2.interceptors = i2
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.i2.type = static
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.i2.key = ip
a1.sources.r2.interceptors.i2.value = 192.168.0.25
```

Then, you can setup avro-router sink like:

```
agent.sinks.routerSink.type = com.datums.stream.AvroRouterSink
agent.sinks.routerSink.hostname = test_host
agent.sinks.routerSink.port = 34541
agent.sinks.routerSink.channel = memoryChannel

# Set sink name
agent.sinks.routerSink.component.name = AvroRouterSink

# Set header name for routing
agent.sinks.routerSink.condition = ip

# Set routing conditions
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions = east,west
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions.east.if = ^192.168.0.12
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions.east.then.hostname = test_host
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions.east.then.port = 34542
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions.west.if = ^192.168.0.25
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions.west.then.hostname = test_host
agent.sinks.routerSink.conditions.west.then.port = 34543
```

Lastly, one more agent for receiving events and writing them to different log files

```
agent.sources = src1 src2 src3
agent.channels = c1 c2 c3
agent.sinks = logger1 logger2 logger3

agent.sources.src1.type = avro
agent.sources.src1.bind = test_host
agent.sources.src1.port = 34531
agent.sources.src1.channel = c1

agent.sources.src2.type = avro
agent.sources.src2.bind = test_host
agent.sources.src2.port = 34532
agent.sources.src2.channel = c2

agent.sources.src3.type = avro
agent.sources.src3.bind = test_host
agent.sources.src3.port = 34533
agent.sources.src3.channel = c3

agent.sinks.logger1.type = logger
agent.sinks.logger1.channel = c1

agent.sinks.logger2.type = logger
agent.sinks.logger2.channel = c2

agent.sinks.logger3.type = logger
agent.sinks.logger3.channel = c3
```